# openlayers:transform from ITM to 900913 is not accurate

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2, israel

I did a custom projection ITM (Israel TM) and I then am doing transform to all the feature before I'm adding them to the map, from ITM to 900913 proj because I want to show the feature on the map.

This is the string for the ITM proj:(I am using it with proj4js)

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31.73439361111111 +lon_0=35.20451694444445 +k=1.0000067 +x_0=219529.584 +y_0=626907.39 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-48,55,52,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

but, when I add the feature like this:

```
features.geometry.transform(ITM, proj900913);
vectors.addFeatures(features);
```

the feature is placed 4 meters to the north and 4 meters to the east, and not in the place it is supposed to be.
its also happening when i am load KML layer.

How can I place the point in the right place?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, very accurate transformations are available from the Survey of Israel, but they are not publicly available. I don't know the accuracy or source of this transformation. It's in ArcGIS with the following direction, method, and parameter values. PROJ4 uses position vector (different rotation convention so all rotation signs have to be changed) and wants **to** WGS84 not **from** WGS84, so all parameter signs need to be changed).

```
WGS84 to Israel
Coordinate Frame
X Axis Translation = -24.0024
Y Axis Translation = -17.1032
Z Axis Translation = -17.8444
X Axis Rotation = -0.33009
Y Axis Rotation = -1.85269
Z Axis Rotation = 1.66969
Scale Difference = 5.4248

Israel to WGS84
Position Vector
X Axis Translation = 24.0024
Y Axis Translation = 17.1032
Z Axis Translation = 17.8444
X Axis Rotation = -0.33009
Y Axis Rotation = -1.85269
Z Axis Rotation = 1.66969
Scale Difference = -5.4248
```

which converts to

```
+towgs84=24.0024,17.1032,17.8444,-0.33009,-1.85269,1.66969,-5.4248
```